# Javascript split blob as strings

Tags: javascript, filereader

Say you parse a text file with fileReader:

```
function show() {
    var file = document.getElementById('myFile');
    var data = file.files[0];
    var fileRead = new FileReader();
    fileRead.onload = function() { document.getElementById('out').appendChild(document.createTextNode(' ' + fileRead.result)) }
    fileRead.readAsText(data);
}
```

How do you split a blob object (raw data) with the split function which works only on strings?

If I convert the blob to string and then call readAsText it reasonably complains that the `data` variable (containing text) is not a blob object.

So, basically I want to use the split function on the blob text object.

Comment: show the blob content and on which character or pattern you want to split on to.

Comment: The blob content is an arbitrary text file. The pattern for the split function could be anything, but for simplicity let's say we split every word (" ").

Comment: Do you want to split the content before you read using readAsText? Or do you want to split fileRead.result?

Comment: Before I read using readAsText

Answer (score -1):

You can just do it in the onload callback.

```
var file = document.getElementById('myfile');
var data = file.files[0];
var var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function() {
    let strings = fileReader.result.split(' '); 
    strings.forEach(function(string) {
        //Your code here
    })
}
fileReader.readAsText(data)
```

If you want blob objects representing each split string, you would have to build the blob objects in the foreach loop.

Comment: i bet after 3.5 years this is now irrelevant and have probably already solved it by himself